# How can I use GitLab pages to host webpages with a user input form, which updates a GitLab repo when saved?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, git, web-applications

I know that GitLab pages is made to host static pages rather than dynamic but I'm not too clear on the borderlines between static and dynamic and whether there are different levels of how dynamic a webpage actually is.

I'm wondering if GitLab pages can be used to host a webpage that:

A) shows content from yaml files in a gitlab repo (in which case I imagine the html file for the webpage would be inside or alongside that repo?)

B) has a form on the webpage with user input boxes such that when this form is saved/sent, the aforementioned GitLab repo is updated.

If this is possible, how would I do this?
If this is not possible then do you have any recommendations about doing this?

Thanks for reading, Milan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no secure way to do what you want from a static site.  In order to write to your repository, you have to have some sort of credentials.  With a static site, those credentials would have to be embedded in the page, so anyone who could download the page could make arbitrary modifications to your repository.  Static sites don't allow the submission of forms to a backend, because there is no backend, only the fixed HTML, CSS, and JavaScript that are downloaded by the user's browser.

In order to securely make this work, you need to have a web server of some sort hosting a backend service written in the language of your choice.  It can then hold credentials that can operate on a repository or database, and accept forms or API requests submitted by a user.  You could also use a Google Form or some other content and then extract the data and periodically embed it into your repo or elsewhere.